# How do I send out the salvage droids?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

how do you send out the salvage droids? everytime I click on them, it takes me through a tutorial, then nothing.

Comment: Which button are you clicking on?

Answer (score 1):

You should press the green button surrounded by a red box in the screen shot below.  It will take you to a mission screen where you can choose where to send the droid.  If you are not seeing the button after 24 hours of waiting, or clicking on it takes you to the tutorial it sounds like you have a bug of some sort.

[image]